# read value only after a window is no longer visible in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Maybe I just don't know where to look or don't exactly understand how threads work, but I have two different JFrames (J1, J2). J1 is the main JFrame that has a drop down menu that will select J2. When this J2 becomes visible I need J1 to wait until J2's foobar value to become something other than -1. I have tried to skin this cat several different ways without success.

What I am trying right now...

```
// located in J1
J2 otherFrame = new J2();
....

private synchronized void getNum() {
    try {
        while (otherFrame.returnNum() == -1) wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    Long myResult = otherFrame.returnNum();
    ...
}



// located in J2
public synchronized Long returnNum() {
    try {
        while (someNum == -1) wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    notify();
    return someNum;
}
```

I am sure this looks dumb, but I need J1 to wait until J2 has a value assigned to someNum. The value will be assigned when the user clicks submit. It isn't doing the job. What am I doing wrong here and (more importantly), if this is a thread thing, where is my concept of threads failing?

Comment: Sounds like a situation where you should use a [modal dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Please let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is not to use a JFrame for your 2nd window but rather a **modal** dialog such as a modal JDialog. This is exactly what this type of top-level window was built for.

This issue is another reason why one should avoid writing Swing classes that extend JFrame, since doing so paints the coder into a corner and limits their options. Much better is to create classes that either extend or are built to create JPanels, since then the JPanel can be placed in a JFrame or modal JDialog if needed, or in another JPanel, or swapped in a CardLayout, or...

Note that use of a JDialog is very similar to that of a JFrame except for a few differences. You should pass into the dialog a reference to the calling window (here your first JFrame), and you should use the constructor that makes the dialog modal, but the API can help you with all of this.

When you make the modal window visible, the code flow in the calling code stops, and does not resume until the JDialog is no longer visible. At that time you can query the components of the JDialog for there state and use it in the calling code.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogEg {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {

        // create JFrame for application
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dialog Eg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField valueField = new JTextField(5);

    public MainPanel() {
        valueField.setFocusable(false); // so user can't interact with it

        add(new JLabel("Value:"));
        add(valueField);
        add(new JButton(new GetValueAction("Get Value")));
    }

    private class GetValueAction extends AbstractAction {
        private SecondPanel secondPanel = new SecondPanel();

        public GetValueAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get JPanel's top level window
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MainPanel.this);

            // create jdialog that is modal
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(win, "Get Value", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.add(secondPanel);

            // so the submit button will be activated when enter pressed:
            dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(secondPanel.getSubmitButton());
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
            dialog.setVisible(true); // **** code flow stops here

            // and resumes here once dialog is no longer visible
            int value = secondPanel.getSpinnerValue();
            valueField.setText("" + value);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SecondPanel extends JPanel {
    private SpinnerModel spinModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(-1, -1, 100, 1);
    private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(spinModel);
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit"));

    public SecondPanel() {
        add(spinner);
        add(submitButton);
    }

    public int getSpinnerValue() {
        return (Integer) spinner.getValue();
    }

    public JButton getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }

    private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SubmitAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int value = getSpinnerValue();

            // get JPanel's top level window
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(SecondPanel.this);
            if (value < 0) {
                String msg = "Submitted value must cannot be negative. Please try again";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, msg, "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                spinner.requestFocusInWindow(); // bring focus back to spinner
            } else {
                spinner.requestFocusInWindow();
                win.dispose();  // get rid of dialog
            }
        }
    }
}
```